# Configuring H2's web console with Spring Boot

Tags: spring-boot, console, h2

I can't seem to figure out how to configure H2's web console with Spring Boot. I've added

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:mem:myschema;
spring.h2.console.enabled=true
spring.h2.console.path=/console
```

To my application.properties, but still there is nothing at localhost:8080/console. H2's driver is my classpath, so I guess that the only condition of the three listed in [the docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-sql.html#boot-features-sql-h2-console) that I might not be fulfilling is

> You are developing a web application

What exactly does it mean? I have `spring-boot-starter-web` as a dependency in my pom.xml, and my start/main is annotated with

```
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@ComponentScan({"com.xxxx"})
```

What am I missing?

Note that I do not want to use MVC.

Comment: That is strange. Even I have the same things in my pom ( springboot, parent, spring-boot-starter-web, h2 dependency). And /console works perfectly fine. Here is my h2-dependency <dependency>
            <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
            <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>

Answer (score 0):

H2 webconsole autoconfiguration is only triggered when spring-web is included.

But all you need to do to start h2 webconsole is run this code

```
org.h2.tools.Server s = org.h2.tools.Server.createWebServer("-web","-webAllowOthers","-webDaemon","-webPort", "8080").start();
...
s.stop(); // if you want to stop
```

You can also do with defining this bean somewhere

```
 @Bean(initMethod="start",destroyMethod="stop")
 public org.h2.tools.Server h2WebConsonleServer () throws SQLException {
   return org.h2.tools.Server.createWebServer("-web","-webAllowOthers","-webDaemon","-webPort", "8080");
 }
```